# Using Selenium ChromeDriver with VBA Error

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm a beginner with both VBA and Selenium so forgive me if this is too obvious. I'm trying to see whether I can make VBA open a Chrome window to check that Selenium works fine, via the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Private MyBrowser As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub TestSelenium()
    
    Set MyBrowser = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    
    MyBrowser.Start
    
End Sub
```

I, however, get the following error:

[image]

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out I had to download Microsoft .NET 3.5 Framework for it to work